# Angular:How to access the value of $ngOptionLabel field of Ng-select?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an ng-select field 
html

```
         <div class="form-group row col-md-12">
              <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="vendorName">Company Type</label>
              <div class="col-md-9 ng-drp-dwn-nkb">

              <ng-select class="custom" [searchable]="true" [multiple]="false" id="companyType" name="companyType" [(ngModel)]="companyType1" #companyType="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': companyType.invalid && (companyType.dirty || companyType.touched) }"
              required>
                <ng-option>Hospital</ng-option>
                <ng-option>Pharmacy</ng-option>
                <ng-option>Distributor</ng-option>
                <ng-option>Laboratory</ng-option>
              </ng-select>
              </div>
              </div>
```

in my ts when log it to console from my ts I receive this output

```
{"$ngOptionLabel":"Pharmacy","disabled":false}
```

this object is bound to CompanyType1 field in my typescript file but I'm not able to access this label using

```
this.companyType1.ngOptionLabel
```

[image]
How can I access this field?

Comment: Cant answer with so less code. Whats `this object is bound to CompanyType1` ?? Are you using any 3rd party library ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek Yes it is bound to companyType1, I have provided the result of consoling companyType1. I have added html code too

Comment: WHat are you logging in console ? `CompanyType1` ?  Can you modify https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngselect-ie7hll?file=app/app.component.ts to replicate what you are facing